# Can a point outside a set in the co-countable topology be the limit point of a sequence in that set?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, solution-verification

Consider the co-countable topology on $\mathbb{R}$, and $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $A = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{p\}$. I was able to show that for any sequence $(a_n) \in \mathbb{R}$ to converge in the co-countable topology, it should eventually be constant. We can easily find a point in $A$ that is the limit point of a sequence in $A$.

But, my question is, can a point outside $A$ be the limit point of a sequence in $A$?

*Here is what I've thought of but I don't know if I'm on the right track*: The only point that lies outside $A$ is $p$. So, can $p$ be a limit point of a sequence $(a_n) \in A$? For $p$ to be the limit point, if we take an open set $U$, $p \in U$, $U \setminus \{p\} \cap A \neq \emptyset$.  But we can never take an open set around $p$ since $\{p\}$ is a closed singleton under this topology. Hence the limit point can never be outside $A$?

I'm new to topology and would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the central question is: "no".
No matter how you interpret "limit point" it should imply "in the closure of".
If $C=\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a sequence, a countable set, in $A$ then $C$ is closed in the co-countable topology and if $p\notin A$ then $\mathbb{R}\setminus C$ is a neighbourhood of $p$ that is disjoint from $C$.

So even if $p$ outside $A$ is in the closure of $A$ it is not in the closure of any countable subset of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful in your terminology:

No point outside $A$ is a *limit of a sequence* from $A$.

But *all* points of $\Bbb R$ are *limit points* of $A$ if $A$ is uncountable.

"Limit point of a sequence" is ambiguous, don't use it....

Answer (score 0):

> But we can never take an open set around $p$

Not true. For example, $\mathbb R$ is an open set around $p$.

Also, the following are all open sets around $p$:

- $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb N$, so long as $p$ is not an integer
- $\mathbb R \setminus \{1\}$, so long as $p$ is not $1$.
- $\mathbb R\setminus\{\pi\}$, so long as $p\neq \pi$.
- $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Z$, so long as $p\notin\mathbb Z$

and so on and so on.

---

You are correct, in general, that $p$ is actually a limit point of $A$, but your proof is not OK. Instead, to restart, work in the following direction:

1. Take $U$ such that $p\in U$.
2. Now you must prove that $U\cap A$ is not empty.
3. Notice that $U\cap A$ is not empty **if and only if** there exists some element $u\in U$ such that $u\neq p$.
4. Prove the existence of the element $u$.